# How to get the "display stream" of a MS Windows window?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I have a program (we will call it the "virtual screen") that create a full screen window and start arbitrary programs, and with the help of hooks ([CBTProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644977(v=vs.85)"")) get handles to windows that started programs create. From those handles I retrieve the content of the windows (using [GetDIBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getdibits)) and displays it in the "virtual screen" window.
Currently, this "virtual screen" copy content of windows and then redraw them, which make it work, sort of like a mirroring software.
Here is how I get the content of a window:

```
struct WindowContent {
    void *pixel;
    int width;
    int height;
};
WindowContent getWindowContent(HWND hWnd, int height, int width)
{
    WindowContent content;
    WINDOWINFO windowInfo;
    GetWindowInfo(hWnd, &windowInfo);
    content.height = windowInfo.rcClient.right - windowInfo.rcClient.left;
    content.width = windowInfo.rcClient.bottom - windowInfo.rcClient.top;
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    HDC captureHdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, content.width, content.height);
    HGDIOBJ oldHdc = SelectObject(captureHdc, hBitmap);
    BitBlt(captureHdc, 0, 0, content.width, content.height, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY|CAPTUREBLT);
    SelectObject(captureHdc, oldHdc);
    DeleteDC(captureHdc);
    BITMAPINFO outputBitmapInfo = {};
    outputBitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    GetDIBits(hdc, hBitmap, 0, 0, NULL, &outputBitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    content.pixel = (BYTE *)malloc(outputBitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);
    outputBitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;  
    outputBitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    GetDIBits(hdc, hBitmap, 0, outputBitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight, content.pixel, &outputBitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    return content;
}
```

My question is, how do I remove the copying part, how can I make an area on my "virtual screen" the window output for those programs ?
Emphasis on the fact that I'm trying to make created windows be the area on the "virtual screen", I don't want an additional window hidden or living on the desktop.
In my research, I've looked into Windows DWM DLLs and found some undocumented function (`SignalRedirectionStartComplete` or `MilConnection_CreateChannel`) which names look linked to what I want to do, but I don't think I should use them, as they are undocumented.
Also, the code is using Win32 API but I don't mind using another Windows API or another language (C#, DX* ...).

Forgot to mention, I have already thought about using the DWM thumbnail stuff, but it's not that reliable enough for what I'm trying to do.
As far as I understand Windows 10 uses DX under the hood for all display output, for GDI, and even for Vulkan / OpenGL programs, and someone used it to make a lib that
gets DX 10 texture from a window (). Is it possible to make something similar, that, for a specific `HWND`, set its "output" to a texture or some region in 
memory (swapchain redirection ?) instead of the screen and then display the output in another program (in my case, on the "virtual screen" window) ?

Answer (score 1):

The DWM was a reasonable place to look. It has some documented functions to get you at least a little closer to what you want.

You can register your window as a "thumbnail" viewer using `DwmRegisterThumbnail`. Then you (probably) call `DwmUpdateThumbnailProperties` to tell it how to draw to your window (e.g., set opacity, rectangle to draw to, and whether to draw the whole source window, or just its client area). When you're done, you call `DwmUnregisterThumbnail` to unhook from displaying it.

This is only a little closer to what you want though--it eliminates your having to copy bitmaps from the source into your own window--but that's about all it does. The target application will still have its own window running elsewhere.

If you want to do more to hide the application, you could create another desktop, and display the application in that desktop. If you don't provide a way to switch desktops, that can keep it pretty well hidden. On the other hand, there are external tools that will let the user change desktops, which would let them see the application directly.

One other avenue to consider (for a subset of applications) would be COM. Part of what COM supports is having a COM server that displays its output inside the frame of some COM client's window. That's no longer nearly the big thing it once was, but (I believe) all the code to support it is still available. But, it only works for applications that are specifically written to support it (which, honestly, isn't a huge number). The code for this isn't exactly trivial either.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the desktop stuff, do you know if there is an API or some headers that I could look into ?